# Add Facebook Authentication in webApplication. Error:(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013

I have spend some days to solve this error. Alas! I am stuck in this problem. I want to add "Facebook Authentication" in my app by using "Visual Studio 2013". But my app is not running correctly. I am getting this Server Error.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/Users/Nabia/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects2/TestOwin/TestOwin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = c:\Users\Nabia\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects2\TestOwin\TestOwin\bin
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: c:\Users\Nabia\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects2\TestOwin\TestOwin\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Nabia\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Nabia/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/00ebcba0/eed1cf84/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Nabia/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/00ebcba0/eed1cf84/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/Users/Nabia/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects2/TestOwin/TestOwin/bin/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

Stack Trace: 


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +0
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start(TStateMachine& stateMachine) +61
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateCoreAsync() +152
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +72
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateAsync() +132
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.<InvokeReplyPathAsync>d__19.MoveNext() +298
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.<InvokeAsync>d__16.MoveNext() +264
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +664
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +287
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +937
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +937
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +287
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +272
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +26
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Infrastructure.ErrorState.Rethrow() +33
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +150
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +42
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +380
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.79.0
```

My web.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-OWIN2-20160208103141.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-OWIN2-20160208103141;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I can't understanding, what is my fault?
Please tell me how can I resolve this error?

Comment: The error itself is **explicitly** stating the issue - re: `Newtonsoft.Json` - which means you should check your `web.config` settings so it matches the `Json.net` library you actually are using/referencing re _"manifest definition does not match assembly reference"_ - If you recently (up/down)graded JSON.net lib version, this can occur (cases where your config isn't updated as expected). Hth

Comment: OK, I have done add web.config file in my question, now tell me what should I do?

Comment: It's not in the config above. I have no idea how you setup your project. You _could_ just remove and add the JSON.Net assembly (again) via Nuget and see if that fixes the references issue (and see if it updates your config file).